# Contact ID: id value of incorrect type: 005360000034sSasS

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I would like to ask what causes these issue? wherein previously it is working as expected, profile? validation rules?

```
({
    getRecordTypes : function(component,event,helper){
        var action = component.get("c.GetAvailableRecordTypeCase");
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === "SUCCESS"){
                var returning = [];
                var recordTypes = response.getReturnValue();
                for(var key in recordTypes){
                    //alert("Record Type Id: "+key+" Name: "+recordTypes[key]);
                    returning.push({value:recordTypes[key],key:key});
                }
                component.set("v.availableRecordTypes",returning);
                component.set("v.retrievedTypes",true);
            }
            else{
                alert("Temporary Error: There is a problem getting the Record Types.");// Temporary, Will be changed to ToastError.
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action); 
    },
    getAccountDetails : function(component,event,helper){
        var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
        var action = component.get("c.getAccount");
        action.setParams({recordId : recordId});
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === "SUCCESS"){
                var name = response.getReturnValue()[0].Name;
                var enrolleeId = response.getReturnValue()[0].Contract_Number__pc;
                component.set("v.accountName",name);
                component.set("v.enrolleeId",enrolleeId);
                helper.getContactDetails(component,event,helper,recordId);
            }
            else{
                alert("Temporary Error: There is a problem getting the parent values.");// Temporary, Will be changed to ToastError.
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    getContactDetails : function(component,event,helper,recordId){
        var action = component.get("c.getContact");
        action.setParams({recordId : recordId});
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === "SUCCESS"){
                if((response.getReturnValue()).length <= 0){
                    helper.createRecordFromCase(component,event);
                }else{
                    //var contactId = response.getReturnValue()[0].Id;
                    var contactId = response.getReturnValue()[0].OwnerId;
                    component.set("v.contactId",contactId);
                    helper.createRecord(component,event);
                }
            }
            else{
                alert("Temporary Error: There is a problem getting the parent values.");
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    createRecord : function(component,event){
        component.set("v.loading",false);
        var recordTypes = component.get("v.availableRecordTypes");
        var recordType = component.get("v.recordTypeId");
        var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
        var contactId = component.get("v.contactId");
        var name = component.get("v.accountName");
        var emplloyeeId = component.get("v.enrolleeId");
        var userId = $A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id");



        var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        createRecordEvent.setParams({
            "entityApiName": "Case",
            "recordTypeId": recordType,
            "defaultFieldValues": {
                'AccountId' : recordId,
                //'ContactId' : contactId,
                'ContactId' : userId,
                'Customer_Name__c' : name,
                'Enrollee_ID__c' : emplloyeeId
            }
        });
        createRecordEvent.fire();
        for(var i=0;i<recordTypes.length;i++){ //unchecks out all the radio button
            document.getElementById("radio-"+recordTypes[i].value).checked = false;
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 005 prefix is a User Id. It never could have worked before; something must have changed. All Contact Id values start with 003. You will want to double-check whatever it is you've done. You must always have the correct Id type for a given field, or you'll get this error.

---

Your source error starts here:

```
var contactId = response.getReturnValue()[0].OwnerId;
```

An owner Id would be a 005 Id, while the previous, commented-out line would have been the correct behavior, a 003 Id. This is exactly why your code is not working as you expect.

Comment: yes you are correct that we are using the user to fill up/prepopulate the contact name wherein previously it is working normal. but now giving such error.

Comment: @Cloud Again, it could not have worked, or should not have worked. 005 is never a contact. Maybe you should include some code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: here is the helper of the component, by the way we are using person account in these and account as well.

Comment: @Cloud See my edit.

Comment: so meaning, even the field contact name is a lookup contact, we can still prepopulate in component the contact name with the userlogin? or using the var contactId = response.getReturnValue()[0].Id; will be possible?

Comment: @Cloud You can populate it with a contact, yes, but not a user Id.

Comment: but we can get the ownerid from the contact right?

Comment: @Cloud yes, you already are doing that.

Comment: because previously we used url hack in here whereinit populates the contact name with userlogin, but when saves it uses the account name/contact id still. wherein  think in Lex component it is impossible to prepopulate the contact name with userlogin

Comment: My question would be how can I get the Contact Name from User wherein in the user there is a contact name since it was a parntner user

Comment: @Cloud query the user table for the contact Id associated with the user.